# How to create my own custom converts class

Tags: scala

I have a very generic message object that I get back from a queue like:

```
case class Message(key: String, properties: Map[String, String])
```

I then have a bunch of very specific classes that represent a message, and I use properties.get("type") to determine which particular message it is:

```
sealed trait BaseMessage
case class LoginMessage(userId: Int, ....) extends BaseMessage
case class RegisterMessage(email: String, firstName: String, ....) extends BaseMessage
```

Now in my code I have to convert from a generic Message to a particular message in many places, and I want to create this in a single place like:

Currently I am doing something like:

```
val m = Message(....)
val myMessage = m.properties.get("type") match {
  case Some("login") => LoginMessage(m.properties("userID"), ...)
  case ...
}
```

**What options do I have in making this less cumbersome in scala?**

Comment: Not using a `Map[String, String]` to store arbitrary properties for starters. Recovering that information isn't going to be easy.

Comment: Shapeless can probably help if you want to stay typesafe

Comment: @MichaelZajac that class is from the message queue system, that cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all your context here, but I can suggest using implicit conversions if you don't want to bring another library in your project. Anyway, implicit conversions can help you separate a lot the implementation or override it "on-the-fly" as needed.

We can start by defining a `MessageConverter` trait that is actually a function:

```scala
/**
  * Try[T] here is useful to track deserialization errors. If you don't need it you can use Option[T] instead.
  */
trait MessageConverter[T <: BaseMessage] extends (Message => Try[T])
```

Now define an object that holds both the implementations and also enables a nice `#as[T]` method on `Message` instances:

```scala
object MessageConverters {
  /**
    * Useful to perform conversions such as:
    * {{{
    *   import MessageConverters._
    *
    *   message.as[LoginMessage]
    *   message.as[RegisterMessage]
    * }}}
    */
  implicit class MessageConv(val message: Message) extends AnyVal {
    def as[T <: BaseMessage : MessageConverter]: Try[T] =
      implicitly[MessageConverter[T]].apply(message)
  }

  // Define below message converters for each particular type

  implicit val loginMessageConverter = new MessageConverter[LoginMessage] {
    override def apply(message: Message): Try[LoginMessage] = {
      // Parse the properties and build the instance here or fail if you can't.
    }
  }
}
```

That's it! It may not be the best solution as implicits bring complexity and they make code harder to follow. However, if you follow a well-defined structure for storing these implicit values and be careful how you pass them around, then you shouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `properties` map to Json and read it as a case class. Assuming that the keys to the map have the same name as your case class fields you can write a formatter using [playjson](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson):

```
object LoginMessage {
    implicit val fmtLoginMessage = Json.format[LoginMessage]
}
```

If the fields don't have the same name you will have to specify the reads object manually. Your code to convert it into a case class would be something like:

```
object BaseMessageFactory {
  def getMessage(msg: Message): Option[BaseMessage] = {
    val propertiesJson = Json.toJson(msg.properties)
    msg.properties.get("type").map {
      case "login" => propertiesJson.as[LoginMessage]
          ...
      case _ => //Some error
    }
  }
}
```

The signature may differ depending on how you want to deal with error handling.